# Accessing private class data type

Tags: c++11

```
class factory final {
private:
    class object final {
    public:
        int x;
    };
public:
inline static std::shared_ptr<object> createObject() { return std::make_shared<object>(); }
};



int main() {
    auto item1 = factory::createObject();   
    std::shared_ptr<factory::object> item2 = factory::createObject();
    return std::getchar();
}
```

Hello. The code above fails to compile with VS2015 because I cannot access private member (class object) of class factory. So far so good and it makes alot of sense. I am curious why does the **auto** line works. It does resolve to correct type and works as intended.

Comment: It's the name of the type that is private, not the type itself. Some people call what you did a "Voldemort type". As in a type that can be used, but not named.